# Displaying pdfs(also images) in Javafx

Tags: java, pdf, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'd like to know how I can display pdf files in Javafx(also images)

I know about JPedalFX, but that isn't free.
Maybe someone can suggest me an extern library (its even better if there's a way without using an extern library) which doesnt cost anything.

Comment: if u r using java version > 8 you could use jpeadal

Comment: Guys, didnt u read it?

Comment: the other question has only answers with solutions using jpedal

Comment: Even if the question wasn't closed as a duplicate, it would still have been closed because it [asks for a library recommendation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251135/1155209).